# Regex Search in Kibana Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to use regex in a search within the message of an elastic search dataset. For some reason, I am not able to pass anything in the search bar that the engine doesn't yell at me for.

I am trying to select a triplet of XXX.XX digits of the form. XXX.XX,XXX.XX,XXX.XX and no matter what I try the engine keeps erroring on me.

Here is my query

```
message: /<000-999>/
```

which gives me the following error.

```
KQLSyntaxError: Expected AND, OR, end of input, whitespace but "<" found. message: "DWP_Magnet, Value: " AND message: /<000-999>/
```

I have read the documentation and my data definitely contains values that I am trying to specify, i.e

```
Value: 311.23, 144.00, 155.01
```

can anyone give me any insights? is there a way to use Lucene regex to create the following expression?

```
/d{3}\.\d{2}
```

Comment: `message: "[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2}"`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Kibana search bar expects a KQL ([Kibana Query Language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html)) expression by default. That expression language [doesn't yet support](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/46855) regular expressions.

You need to [switch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/search.html#_search_your_data) from KQL to the [Lucene expression language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) which does support [regular expressions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html) by clicking on the `KQL` popup located at the end of the search bar.

[image]

Then you can use the regular expression, such as the one provided by @unigeek:

```
message: /[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}/
```

Comment: @Mario Please create a new thread with your specific issue

Comment: Done. Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72767878/10452700).

Answer (score 5):

You can simply wrap your regex in forward slashes like this:

```
message: /[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}/
```

But I think you already knew this. Maybe it's just unclear about what regex you need--this is a very common circumstance with regex.

EDIT 1: Note that Elasticsearch uses Lucene and not the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) library, so I believe using 'd' is not possible to match a single digit.

EDIT 2: Useful [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).
[image]