# Problem with using regex-based search in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64998539/10452700) I used proposed regex `\"?\$\{(?:jndi|lower|upper|env|sys|java|date|::-j)[^\s]*\"` to find `jndi`-signatures are used in *useragent* field of web-requests once by Lucene it doesn't work? please see the screenshot below:

[image: img]

Example: `[27/Feb/2022:07:26:09 +0000] xxxx.xx.xx.xxx "-" "GET /xampp/cgi.cgi HTTP/1.1" 403 "-b" 0b 2ms "${jndi:ldap://log4shell-generic-W767eV31Ltd9L3OB6vXK${lower:ten}.w.nessus.org/nessus}" xxx.xx.xx.xxx 15638 "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx" "-" - - TLSv1.2 -,-,-` It doesn't work with(out) caution marks even I checked `/.*n/` based on this [source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_regular_expressions).

Comment: do you have message field which is contaning example value provided in question ? or you want to search in `useragent` field ?

Comment: I do have *message* field but I didn't show in screenshot due to data privacy issue. Even I don't know if it is possible to apply our search over specific field. Main problem is used regex doesn't work/search while I use *Lucene* instead of KQL based on above-mentioned post.