# Kibana regex query on the UI interface

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I am trying to search some logs

```
queryResults: time: 0.079 / 0 rows: 165 sql: select * from ( ( select name, sum(age) as total,
queryResults: time: 10.079 / 0 rows: 165 sql: select * from ( ( select name, sum(age) as total,
queryResults: time: 1.079 / 0 rows: 165 sql: select * from ( ( select name, sum(age) as total,
```

Using this search param:

```
message: "select * from ( ( select name, sum(age) as total,"
```

and the `Filter` as

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message.keyword": "/time: [1-9].+/"
    }
  }
}
```

This works on https://regex101.com/r/z7V64Z/2
But I cannot make this work on the Elastic Search UI.
This can save me HOURS of going through logs.

Can the experts help?

Note: I did refer this link - [Regex Search in Kibana Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64996493/regex-search-in-kibana-elasticsearch), did not help much

Expected output:
Only logs which exceed 1sec+ in SQL execution time
e.g.

```
queryResults: time: 10.079 / 0 rows: 165 sql: select * from ( ( select name, sum(age) as total,
queryResults: time: 1.079 / 0 rows: 165 sql: select * from ( ( select name, sum(age) as total,
```

Comment: Did you try to follow the official syntax: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are searching a keyword field, which indexes the entire field as a single token, you need to write a regex that matches the entire token, not part of it. So, something like this should work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message.keyword": ".*time: [1-9]\\..*"
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use numeric ranges like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message.keyword": {
        "value": ".*time: <5-100>\\..*",
        "flags": "INTERVAL"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please also note that by default elasticsearch generates a mapping that will not index strings longer than 256 bytes into keyword field. So, if these messages are longer than 256 bytes, they will not be found even with regex queries that I showed above.